# Django could not import settings after import a model in a python script

Tags: python, django, django-wsgi

After import one of my models in a python script, when I run the localhost server, I get this **erro**r, I have been reading, but all my tries were a fail:

```
ubuntu@INN0095_VM2:~/env_Compass4D/Compass4D$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'Compass4D.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named Compass4D.settings
```

**My sys.path:**

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']
```

**manage.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Compass4D.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

**wsgi.py:**

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Compass4D.settings")

# This application object is used by any WSGI server configured to use this
# file. This includes Django's development server, if the WSGI_APPLICATION
# setting points here.
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: well, is you folder with settings in sys.path? I did not see it there.

Comment: sys.path.insert(1,'env_Compass4D/Compass4D/settings.py')
>>> print sys.path
['', 'env_Compass4D/Compass4D/settings.py',...]

Comment: the error is still there, and when I close python console, sys path is restored without the path that I had inserted previusly

Comment: I am thinking that the problem may be the fact that I have settings.py and manage.py in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

I confirm the problem was that I had manage.py, settings.py and wsgi.py in the same folder, then you can not write appName.settings in the path import conf, thanks guys.